# ASCIIコード表の作り方に関して

Tags: c

32～127のASCIIコード(16進、10進、キャラクタ)を表示します。
(0～31番は画面に表示できない文字なので、表示しません)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int x, y;       /*ループカウンタ*/
    char c;         /*キャラクタ番号*/

    for(x = 2; x < 8; x++)
        printf("16: 10:c | ");
    printf("\n");
    for(x = 2; x < 8; x++)
        printf("---------+-");
    printf("\n");

    for(y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    {
        for(x = 2; x < 8; x++)
        {
            c = x * 16 + y;
            printf("%2x:%3d:%c | ", c, c, c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

こちらは(株)アンクの｢Cの絵本｣という参考書からなのですが、上記のプログラムだと実行時にエラーが出ます。何故なのでしょうか。

Comment: 4つ目の`for`文で評価式の部分が`x < 8;;`でセミコロンが一つ余計にありますが、こちらは単なる貼り付けミスか、元々のソースも間違っているのどちらでしょう？また、単に「エラーが出る」だけでなく、実際に表示されたエラー内容を編集から追記してみてください（実行時ではなくコンパイルの段階でエラーな気がします）。

Comment: main関数って返り値なくていいんでしたっけ？

Comment: 編集履歴のコメントでは解決されたような感じですが、"実行時"というのは"コンパイルを実行するとき"ということだったのでしょうか？余分なセミコロンによるコンパイルエラーが原因だったのでしたら、既にその旨の回答がついていますからその回答を承認することができます。

Comment: エラーメッセージを追記してください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントレベルで申し訳ないですが、、、

127 (0x7F) も印刷できない文字では?
cubickさんのコメントにあるように、 ; が余分でコンパイルエラーの気がします。
コンパイル環境と、エラーメッセージがあった方が良いです。

あと、「Cの絵本」がいつ頃の Cか分かりませんが、(初版 2002年?)
古い Cでは、main() の戻り値も必須でないですね。(最近のだと警告がでるでしょうか?)